# Android external library access

Tags: java, gradle, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am attempting to access an Android shared object from an Android application that I am working on.  Based on online information on how to do this I have created the following folder structure within my project:

```
|--app:
|--|--src:
|--|--|--main
|--|--|--|--jniLibs
|--|--|--|--|--armeabi
|--|--|--|--|--|--.so Files
|--|--|--|--|--armeabi-v7a
|--|--|--|--|--|--.so Files
```

In my java code the stringFromJNI method which I am trying to call from the shared object is not being resolved.  I am not sure what I need to do to fix this as I have read similar examples online.

Here is the Java code for the application:

```
package com.example.ndktest.androidlibcall;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class AndroidLibCall extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static String TAG = "AndroidLibCall";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Log.d(TAG, getRegister());
        Log.d(TAG, stringFromJNI);
    }

    static {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("libhello-jni");
        }
        catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e)
        {
            System.out.println("UnsatisfiedLinkError in static block");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    flavorDimensions "versionCode"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ndktest.androidlibcall"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jnilibs']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        x86 {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "x86"
            }
        }
        arm {
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Java class should declare a **native** method, e.g.

```
private native String stringFromJNI();
```

Now you can call it as any other method of your class, e.g.

```
Log.d(TAG, stringFromJNI() );
```

*Don't miss the parentheses!*

As for the **build.gradle**, you don't need `externalNativeBuild` there when you supply the library in **jniLibs** folder. Your `productFlavors` section will fail with Android Studio 3.0 or higher, because you picked it up from an outdated example. But you can simply remove it, because again **jniLibs** folder will take care of this.

The unresolved question is whether after above changes your **ndktest** will work. This depends on what you have in the C++ code, and how you built the file **liblibhello-jni.so**.

*Note that your Java code looks for the peculiar file as I show above*.

If your prebuilt file is named **libhello-jni.so**, you must change your Java:

```
System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
```

Comment: Oh gosh I completely forgot this, I knew it was something simple.  Thank you!